# presentModalViewController not working

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a navigation controller based application. There are a number of view controllers. 
The method pushViewController:animated: works fine and the view controllers are pushed correctly.

However, presenting a modal view controller from the viewcontroller or navigation controller like below does not work. The code does not give any errors, and executes in debugging, but the screen is not shown.

I tried

```
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Appreciate any pointers please!

Comment: how do you create the vc? can you post a larger portion of the code?

Comment: please post the code that allocates and initializes vc, so we can see if it even exists =)

something like `YourModalViewControllerClass *vc = [[YourModalViewControllerClass alloc]init];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted looks fine. Make sure `vc.modalTransitionSyle` is set to something reasonable, make sure `vc` is not `nil` in `presentModalViewController:animated`. If you're targeting 5.x and ignoring 4.x, you should move to the new`presentViewController:animated:completion` idiom, the others are on their way out of service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured out what the problem was. It was my navigation controller set up. I had originally set my app as a tab based controller , and when I changed it to nav controller, the links got messed up. So, the nav controller was not behaving as expected.